# Float number validation in angular for min and max fields

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I need for min and max fields validation on float number, that is 1.59 is allowed but anything higher than is not allowed like 1.60 also 1.00 should be the minimum value. Here i am used angular form for submit the data.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943807/float-range-validation-using-angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943807/float-range-validation-using-angularjs)

Comment: `<input type="number" min="1" max="1.59" ng-model="something"/>`

Comment: @JensonRaby What does that mean? I have the feeling you want a time picker, not a number field.

Comment: any update on this thread

Answer (score 1):

Use `min` and `max` directives for this as follows,

```
<div>
    <form name="myForm">
        <input type="number" min="1" max="1.59" ng-model="enteredNumber" name="numberName" />
    </form>

    Validity of the entered number = {{ myForm.numberName.$valid }}
</div>
```

You can check whether the number entered is valid or not by using `$valid`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this pattren

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"

<input type="number" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="myDecimal" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" />
<span>Is a valid decimal? {{myForm.myDecimal.$valid}}</span>
```